# Log File Analyser for PC

Tags: logging

The standard log analysis tool provided by my hoster shows very limited information (trying to force me to buy a full fledged analysis package). I have downloaded the log files and would like to evaluate them locally on my PC (Windows or Linux). Any tips? I could only find web-based analysis programs that run on the server.

Comment: I used to use webtrends but I don't know if it exists anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try [Deep Log Analyzer](http://www.deep-software.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of log analysis packages that can be used.  Some of the server based log analysis tools can be installed and run on your local machine to simulate a server.  [SmarterStats](http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/web-analytics-seo-software.aspx), [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), and [WebTrends](http://www.webtrends.com/) are a few good examples (although I'm not sure if WebTrends has a free version).

Steve Schofield (Windows Server MVP for IIS) lists a few examples on his [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2007/09/04/log-analsyis-software-for-iis.aspx).

Answer (score -4):

The best “Log file analyser” is yourself.  An analyzer might not see everything.  Reading the log yourself is better than using an application.

Comment: You can read and make sense of hundreds of thousands of lines in a log file? You must be superman!

Comment: How on earth one is supposed to read and analyse thousands of lines of logs, create graphs/pie charts/pdf reports for management, break results into country/region, highlight IP/domains/urls etc?

Comment: There is a difference between 'data' (raw materials) and 'information' (finished goods).  Log files provide you with data.  Log file analytics software can help filter and process that data into useful information that can be used for decision making.